# How to do debugging in Ruby Mine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine, rubymine-7

I am using Ruby mine for developing rails application. I tried to use a built-in debugger but I was not getting any results. 
It always throws some error. Do I need to install any plugin or gems for this? 
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: [Ruby Mine Debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/debugging.html) Read the **Important Note** at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need a debase gem for it, but you`ll be asked by Ruby Mine to install it. 
Please, post the error message. I`ll edit the answer after this.